# Vega-lite chart fails when graphing on utcmonthdate

Tags: vega-lite

Why is this vega-lite graph failing to display any data? The y-axis is supposed to display the total hours and the x-axis is supposed to display a series of month-day combinations. Instead, it displays nothing at all. If I change the y-axis type from "temporal" to "ordinal", it displays the data all stacked up in a single column, instead of spread out over a series of days, so I know the data is good.

[Vega Editor Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAxtBgOYD2ATgJ7wgDCKGEAdgJbMkgA0IA+lmTQUCGeKAAWgijjgB2HpCii4IAEwAGDQFp1AFi0BGVQBV16uGYvqAdGfUAtEAF8nXQsXLVaDJmw7c+ASERMRBJIRkDdQViWg1tPR0ANlNzSzNbM0cXNxAiJU8aFQBBAgJBZih2Th5+KRCEMKlI6PBYlXj1HX11WVSrK0yHZ1d3AsoikFLytErqgLrg5Qlm+CSYpTjNLsSDA370mzts0byPCdoABQoyEgoIAFsH+dqg4WWmiPgAZg3lNW23UM3wOaSOWRGuXypAuKmut3uTxegXqH3C0ngqj+WwS+gMAFZQYNjpCxjCvHCbndHs9-K9UaF0TJVFi2psOoDdn1DsSITkyYUrlTEbSaiilozVnB8diObjDABOIkZEn8s7jCkgACKxQWbwaKy+cAJsoB8tU+x5Kr5p2hgpUOr1DMaTJ+rUU-06QNUIKt4OGartsO1uvpEpdUu+7vaZp2eN0yv9JwAuq4QFB7swsAAzSgPPCgFBkMgAazQAAdaEGvDxszd841FLBGsxHv9xKwoFhrB2uwFkOhsAX01Ry-8fCxkYt3qEwBhyxAKFAHhhKrQAFKTqCUVioUkjse0aYVKp08UzxvzxfL1dQWgAMXYLBCaqgo-+8OpSLP04N4CvS4rmuKgAEoAAQsGAYEACL7m+h4OqG55-nOC6AbetDgZBMEjKmPAlhgkzwaItasBgKBgDIuDIRg1iodeQF3qmtqoAQaAoDGihoA81jVlQADUADkYFaGBgn8VxDy4IJv60fR6GVIJyYBBAMggIwJCrmAzi5FUK4AKpsHeKhoFABAPGQlTiB6ATZmRFG0LJdGxDwqm0DZLEoGxHHsmy3HWE5rquWprqnBAJB3KQ7T4CAZCVioWDcbZ9naSoQUgG5KjbjAKChcmPB3II5YAEZFNRGlaQENk8NlqCuqm+UgA8i4lrQxWLgEq7lGA8yNAAHqEekYIZna0KZ5mWVA1kuSAdnkalbIkQe-xKA85aUHuaZFKAc0OVlZA5elxG0AAjmgLBVDAVSIKIablEWFChLtC0Vcw2k1Z2jC0AAslQYEADKkJVNXvrQzBkLSe48K9qWgDuGH7ZWLguEAA)

```
{
  "data": {    
          "values": [ 
            {"category": "Cleaning", "_source": {"hours": 7, "date": "2020-04-12T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "Cleaning", "_source": {"hours": 10, "date": "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "Accounting", "_source": {"hours": 10, "date": "2020-04-07T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "Accounting", "_source": {"hours": 6, "date": "2020-04-11T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "Programming", "_source": {"hours": 3, "date": "2020-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "Programming", "_source": {"hours": 2, "date": "2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "Programming", "_source": {"hours": 22, "date": "2020-04-17T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "Programming", "_source": {"hours": 5, "date": "2020-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "QA", "_source": {"hours": 15, "date": "2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "QA", "_source": {"hours": 30, "date": "2020-04-23T00:00:00.000Z"}},
            {"category": "QA", "_source": {"hours": 30, "date": "2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z"}}
          ]},
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "category",
      "from": {
        "data": {    
          "name": "hits.hits",
          "values": [
              {"type": "Cleaning", "_source": { "department": "Janitorial"}},
              {"type": "Accounting", "_source": { "department": "Finance"}},
              {"type": "Programming", "_source": { "department": "R and D"}},
              {"type": "QA", "_source": { "department": "R and D"}}
          ]},
        "key": "type",
        "fields": ["_source.department"]
      }
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.category+' - '+datum['_source.department']", "as": "legend"},
    {"timeUnit": "utcmonthdate", "field": "_source.date", "as": "date"},
    {"calculate": "datum._source.hours", "as": "hours"},
    {"aggregate": 
      [{"op": "sum", "field": "hours", "as": "totalhours"}], 
      "groupby": ["legend", "date", "totalhours"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"timeUnit": "utcmonthdate",
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {"field": "totalhours", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "legend",
      "title": "My Legend",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {"orient": "top"}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `timeUnit` is defined via a transform, you must ensure that any input has been parsed as a date. You can do this using a calculate transform with the [toDate](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#toDate) expression:

```
{"calculate": "toDate(datum._source.date)", "as": "date"}
```

Here is how it would look in your example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAxtBgOYD2ATgJ7wgDCKGEAdgJbMkgA0IA+lmTQUCGeKAAWgijjgB2HpCii4IAEwAGDQFp1AFi0BGVQBV16uGYvqAdGfUAtEAF8nXQsXLVaDJmw7c+ASERMRBJIRkDdQViWg1tPR0ANlNzSzNbM0cXNxAiJU8aFQBBAgJBZih2Th5+KRCEMKlI6PBYlXj1HX11WVSrK0yHZ1d3AsoikFLytErqgLrg5Qlm+CSYpTjNLsSDA370mzts0byPCdoABQoyEgoIAFsH+dqg4WWmiPgAZg3lNW23UM3wOaSOWRGuXypAuKmut3uTxegXqH3C0ngqj+WwS+gMAFZQYNjpCxjCvHCbndHs9-K9UaF0TJVFi2psOoDdn1DsSITkyYUrlTEbSaiilozVnB8diObjDABOIkZEn8s7jCkgACKxQWbwaKy+cAJsoB8tU+x5Kr5p2hgpUOr1DMaTJ+rUU-06QNUIKt4OGartsO1uvpEpdUu+7vaZp2eN0yv9JwAuq4QFB7swsAAzSgPPCgFBkMgAazQAAdaEGvDxszd841FLBGsxHv9xKwoFhrB2uwFkOhsAX01Ry-8fCxkYt3qEwBhyxAKFAHhhKrQAFKTqCUVioUkjse0aYVKp08UzxvzxfL1dQWgAMXYLBCaqgo-+8OpSLP04N4CvS4rmuKgAEoAAQsGAYEACL7m+h4OqG55-nOC6AbetDgZBMEjKmPAlhgkzwaItasBgKBgDIuDIRg1iodeQF3qmtqoAQaAoDGihoA81jVlQADUADkYFaGBgn8VxDy4IJv60fR6GVIJyYBBAMggIwJCrmAzhQqx7Extu0HEAAFJJ1iyXRxAAJQqWpHo6aAVQrgAqmwd4qGgUAEA8ZCVOI9mkeR2kqAFICqbQ9ksSgbEceybLceZ+q0a6PDhSorqnBAJB3KQ7T4CAZCVioWDcQE2ZkRRtApWFanbjAKAZcmPB3II5YAEZFNRGlaQEoV1agrqpk1IAPIuJa0G1i4BKu5RgPMjQAB6hE5GCuZ2tCed5vlQP5sSBZVIV7Qe-xKA85aUHuaZFKA5VBbQ-UNasPDEbQACOaAsFUMBVIgohpuURYUKEt0HeppA9c9naMLQACyVBgQAMuDzDac9760MwZC0nuPDdSjoQ7hhKjbpWLguEAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "category": "Cleaning",
        "_source": {"hours": 7, "date": "2020-04-12T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "Cleaning",
        "_source": {"hours": 10, "date": "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "Accounting",
        "_source": {"hours": 10, "date": "2020-04-07T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "Accounting",
        "_source": {"hours": 6, "date": "2020-04-11T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "Programming",
        "_source": {"hours": 3, "date": "2020-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "Programming",
        "_source": {"hours": 2, "date": "2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "Programming",
        "_source": {"hours": 22, "date": "2020-04-17T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "Programming",
        "_source": {"hours": 5, "date": "2020-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "QA",
        "_source": {"hours": 15, "date": "2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "QA",
        "_source": {"hours": 30, "date": "2020-04-23T00:00:00.000Z"}
      },
      {
        "category": "QA",
        "_source": {"hours": 30, "date": "2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z"}
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "category",
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "name": "hits.hits",
          "values": [
            {"type": "Cleaning", "_source": {"department": "Janitorial"}},
            {"type": "Accounting", "_source": {"department": "Finance"}},
            {"type": "Programming", "_source": {"department": "R and D"}},
            {"type": "QA", "_source": {"department": "R and D"}}
          ]
        },
        "key": "type",
        "fields": ["_source.department"]
      }
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.category+' - '+datum['_source.department']",
      "as": "legend"
    },
    {"calculate": "toDate(datum._source.date)", "as": "date"},
    {"timeUnit": "utcmonthdate", "field": "date", "as": "date"},
    {"calculate": "datum._source.hours", "as": "hours"},
    {
      "aggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "hours", "as": "totalhours"}],
      "groupby": ["legend", "date", "totalhours"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"timeUnit": "utcmonthdate", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "totalhours", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "legend",
      "title": "My Legend",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {"orient": "top"}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]